# Django PyTest - Database access not allowed Error even with django_db and fixtures?

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I am learning PyTest in django and I encountered problem that I cannot solve.

I am getting this error:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting prices_tool/tests/test_views.py ____________________________________________________________________________________________________________
prices_tool/tests/test_views.py:9: in <module>
    from prices_tool.views import results
prices_tool/views.py:14: in <module>
    from prices_tool.forms import SearchForm, FreeSearchForm
prices_tool/forms.py:7: in <module>
    class FreeSearchForm(forms.Form):
prices_tool/forms.py:11: in FreeSearchForm
    for make in makes:
../prices_tool-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:287: in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
../prices_tool-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:1308: in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
../prices_tool-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:111: in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size):
../prices_tool-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:1108: in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
../prices_tool-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:1154: in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
../prices_tool-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py:26: in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
../prices_tool-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py:259: in cursor
    return self._cursor()
../prices_tool-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py:235: in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
E   RuntimeError: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.
========================================================================================================================== short test summary info ===========================================================================================================================
ERROR prices_tool/tests/test_views.py - RuntimeError: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================================================================================================================== 1 error in 0.47s ==============================================================================================================================
```

It seems that I cannot import any method from my views.py. Of course I tried adding `@pytest.mark.django_db` it did not work. I googled around and found some posts here and I added in my `conftest.py` this:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def enable_db_access_for_all_tests(db):
    pass
```

And when that did not work I even tried with this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup():
    settings.DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'path/to/dbfile.sqlite3',
    }
```

But none of this fix or changed error message. How can I fix this?

Thanks and Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeError: Database access not allowed, use the "django\_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional\_db" fixtures to enable it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63717925/runtimeerror-database-access-not-allowed-use-the-django-db-mark-or-the-db)

Comment: I don't think so. But I found some solution that is working, I am not sure if it is smart but it's working.

Answer (score 2):

I have found solution to my problem. I am not sure if it is a smart thing to do, but now it's obvious solution.

Just move import of problematic view BELOW `@pytest.mark.django_db`.

For example:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestViews:
    def test_view(self, client):
        path = reverse('results')
        request = RequestFactory().get(path)
        request.user = mixer.blend(User)

        context = {
            'info': info
        }

        from prices_tool.views import results
        response = results(request, context)
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

In this way you will avoid errors that are occurring because some view is importing db stuff.

Comment: It’s possible you have some global elements in the import that are executed when imported, e.g not wrapped up in a function

Comment: I'm ready to kiss you. Thank you so much body! It works and it's makes me laughing, your solution.